# In android studio I want to change the format of entering a int 1000000 in a edit text like 1.000.000 but I can't

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want user to enter the amount of money so my app do the math I done all the things and it works great even I made the output to show numbers like 1.000.000 with the help of:

```
public static String splitDigits(float number) {
        return new DecimalFormat("###,###,###").format(number);
    }
```

But for edit text I don't know how to do it I want to make the number easy to read for the user when entering the number in edit text is there any way to use this method for edit text?

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is textchangelistener of edittext

```
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            edittext.setText(splitDigit(Float.parseFloat(charSequence.toString())));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```